# error in palindrome checking code in x86 assembly for DOS

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

This code should check if the string is a palindome or not.

But it always prints "yes" for any string. How can I fix this problem?

I think the error is in in some jump instruction.

What is the error?

```
include inout.asm
.model small,c
.stack 200h
.data
    pal       db "rear"
    ;pal      db 200 dup("mohammad")
    pal_len   equ $ - pal  - 1
    szYes     db "yes$"
    szNo      db "no$"
.code
.startup

;call gets,offset pal
call puts,offset pal

    lea     si, pal
    lea     di, pal
    add     di, pal_len
    mov     cx, 0
CheckIt:
    mov     al, byte ptr [si]
    mov     dl, byte ptr [di]
    cmp     al, dl
    jne     No
    inc     si
    dec     di
    inc     cx
    cmp     cx, pal_len
    JNE     CheckIt
    lea     dx,szYes

    jmp done

No:
    lea     dx,szNo
done:   
    .exit
end
```

Comment: anybody and help me ?

Comment: Use a debugger to see what your code is doing: http://kipirvine.com/asm/debug/Debug_Tutorial.pdf

Comment: ok thx ,,, do you know how I can debug the doce using tasm ?

Comment: TASM is an assembler, not a debugger. There is Turbo Debugger (haven't used). [DeGlucker](http://vagsoft.chat.ru/dg.html) (freeware) and Gametools (G3X) (probably can be still found somewhere) can be useful too. And older versions of SoftIce for DOS can still be found somewhere. But I don't know about recent developments in debuggers for DOS (if any, who codes in DOS these days?).

Comment: i know << but my friend tell me theres a way to debug it using tasm
amd i try it ,,no porblem

Comment: You can debug without a debugger too, just add a lot of printing code all around your code to output the values of registers and memory, that's also called printf debugging. How to do that (I strongly recommend learning to use a proper debugger instead): learn how to print strings in DOS x86 assembly, and use that code to print debug strings in your code. Anyway, I really recommend you to learn to use a debugger and not go the printf debugging way.

Comment: By the way: `pal db 200 dup("mohammad")` is not a palindrome... but for example `pal db 200 dup("mohammaddammahom")` is a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

I see no printing code in your question. So I added my own:

```
No:
    lea dx,szNo
done:
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    .exit
end
```

and assembled it with MASM 6.11, and it printed "no" for "rear", as it should, and worked correctly for other strings I tried too. I don't know about the printing code your use.

However, you have other bug in your code: it does not handle strings of length of 1 properly, but keep comparing whatever bytes there are in memory after `pal`. This happens because you store into `pal_len` a relative **offset** of the last character, and not the string **length**, and you increment `cx` with `inc cx` before checking if `cx` already equals `pal_len`.

So here:

```
pal_len equ $ - pal  - 1
```

defines `pal_len` to have value of 3 for `"rear"`, instead of 4, because you subtract 1. It works without problems for string length other than 1 here (the last character gets compared anyway already with the first character), but fails for string length of 1. Naming a variable or a macro with something like "len" as in **length** and using it to mean an **offset** is not a good idea, because it causes confusion.

So, here's the entire fixed code:

```
.model small,c
.stack 200h
.data
    pal db "a"
    pal_len equ $ - pal
    szYes     db "yes$"
    szNo      db "no$"
.code
.startup

    lea     si, pal
    lea     di, pal
    add     di, (pal_len-1)
    mov     cx, 0
CheckIt:
    mov     al, byte ptr [si]
    mov     dl, byte ptr [di]
    cmp     al, dl
    jne     No
    inc     si
    dec     di
    inc     cx
    cmp     cx, pal_len
    JNE     CheckIt
    lea     dx,szYes

    jmp     done

No:
    lea     dx,szNo
done:
    mov     ah,9
    int     21h
    .exit
end
```